# Enabling syntax and syntax folding in vim with large C file makes completion slow

Tags: c, vim

When I have syntax on in a large C file (about 8000) lines
the completion ctrl-p and ctrl-n are very slow (more than 20). When I turn syntax off then completion takes less than a second.

I figured out a minimal way of reproducing this behaviour. Use an empty .vim folder and create a .vimrc with only these lines:

```
set syntax on
set foldmethod=syntax
```

When you open a large C file, completion (and even general editing) becomes very slow.

Edit:

This behavior was due to the fact that I was using a beta version. I am not sure if I should delete this question altogether, or leave it so if others have the same problem can have some clue about it.

Comment: "this behavior was due to the fact that I was using a beta version" I experienced the same problems on the final release of Vim7.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your completion is being adjusted by the syntax highlighting file. To see if this is the case, and make completion lean and fast regardless, try

```
:set complete=.
```

which will make completion only use the current file.

read more about the complete options with

```
:help 'complete'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I had tried that before, I figured out that the problem is in the foldmethod setting, not sure if anything can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Vim is sometimes slow to (especially for ins-completion) in large files due to `foldmethod=syntax`

From :help todo:

> - Slow combination of folding and PHP syntax highlighting.  Script to
>     reproduce it.  Caused by "syntax sync fromstart" in combination with patch
>     7.2.274.  (Christian Brabandt, 2010 May 27) Generally, folding with
>     'foldmethod' set to "syntax" is slow.  Do profiling to find out why.

The [FastFold plugin](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) makes it so folds are only recalculated on save (so you're always using `foldmethod=manual` -- but the folds are calculated with `foldmethod=syntax` or whatever you had set before).

This solved the problem for me. Now I can use compl-whole-line completion in my 5000 line C++ file and it's instant and snappy instead of taking minutes and unresponsive.