# Syntax highlighting causes terrible lag in Vim

Tags: vim

I love Vim. But its giving me hard times right now.

I use a lot of plugins and during the last 6 months, I've found a lot of awesome ones. But my Vim got really sluggish too. I do constant cleanups, but it doesn't help much.

I'm at the point, where Vim is completely unusable. It feels like it renders at 2-5 frames per second, switching tabs/buffers takes about a second, scrolling with `hjkl` is awfully terrible, the lag is so bad, even typing a sentence in insert mode is confusing (due to lag).

*Edit: Actually, when I open fresh instance of Vim its OK-ish, but than within 15 minutes it becomes unusable.*

I've just spent 4 hours trying to figure out which plugin or config is causing the pain. I was unsuccessful.

However, I did find out, that removal of this setting causes all the lag to go away:
`syntax on`

These 3 lines in conjunction with syntax make everything even worse.

```
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme candyman
```

Interesting. So, syntax highlighting is turning Vim from super snappy to incredibly sluggish?

I tried enabling syntax in "clean" mode:
`vim -u NONE`

And its not an issue there.

So what seems to be the issue is Syntax Highlighting in combination with one or more of my plugins. I tried disabling bunch, no luck.

Is there any way to do profiling? I'm fairly exhausted from manual testing.

Has anyone had similar experience? Maybe take a quick peek into my `.vimrc`, see if anything rings a bell.
https://bitbucket.org/furion/dotfiles

**SOLUTION:**
The plugin causing the mess was:

```
Bundle "gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque.git"
```

I recommend reading the answers tho, good insights.

**Edit (1 month later):** The coloresque plugin has seen some improvements.

Comment: Based on your latest edit, I'm guessing something is leaking something. Do you see the memory footprint of vim growing (even slightly, but constantly)? It could be for example a plugin or even vim that keeps a map of somethings which is ever-growing, either because the plugin is buggy, or you have set some setting in Vim to a really large value (wild guess, but for example undo history).

Comment: Another way how I can trigger lagg right away, is by going into .vimrc and `so %` it. How can I test for leaks?

Comment: I don't really know. Doing that seems like reloading the plugin causes the leak? Most likely you need to wait for [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) to come answer you!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. The lag should be gone by as of latest version(I'm using my plugin myself). Can you please try the latest version. Sorry again.

Comment: It does seem snappier...

Comment: @KonstantinGorodinskiy I've now installed it on my production machine as well, will report problems if any.

Comment: @KonstantinGorodinskiy It does seem to be much better, however on lines where coloring is done, the lag is still quite terrible, on other lines, not really.

Comment: I raised a bug https://github.com/gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque/issues/14
Will try to reproduce and fix asap.

Comment: Great tips here... my problem was cursorline and relativenumber... (I'm on a very old, slow server)

Comment: I don't use any crazy plugins. What was making Vim dog-slow here on large files, in the year 2020, was an accidental `set foldmethod=syntax` left behind in my `.vimrc` lord knows when.  Simple edits would take many seconds to complete on a file of over 10,000 lines.  It looked like syntax highlighting was to blame because `set syntax off` made the problem go away; but actually the slowdown was due to Vim recalculating fold-levels from syntax, probably over the entire file, for every edit. Basically @fwoeck's answer from 2013.

Comment: Hello OP! I just came across your post after doing some research on this same issue. Your mileage may vary, but on my end, a plugin called vim-hexokinase provides the same coloring without bogging down my vim performance like the many others I've tried. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have `autocmd` spam. You should wrap all of your autocmd statements in groups which clear the group before re-adding the autocmds. It looks like your `.vimrc` has most autocmds commented-out, so maybe there is a plugin that is causing the issue. Check the output of this command:

```
:au CursorMoved
```

If there's a bunch of duplicate handlers there, that's your problem.

Here's an example of autocmd discipline from [my .vimrc](https://github.com/justinmk/config/blob/c489f4dea45d36ac94b97bf79118860fac88a154/.vim/vimrc):

```
augroup vimrc_autocmd
  autocmd!
  "toggle quickfix window
  autocmd BufReadPost quickfix map <buffer> <leader>qq :cclose<cr>|map <buffer> <c-p> <up>|map <buffer> <c-n> <down>

  autocmd FileType unite call s:unite_settings()
  " obliterate unite buffers (marks especially).
  autocmd BufLeave \[unite\]* if "nofile" ==# &buftype | setlocal bufhidden=wipe | endif

  " Jump to the last position when reopening a file
  autocmd BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif

  " ...etc...

augroup END
```

The `autocmd!` at the beginning of the `augroup` block clears out the current group (`vimrc_autocmd`, in this case) before re-adding the autocmds.

Comment: 3 autocommands from `:au CursorMoved`. All 3 from plugins. I will rework my `.vimrc` to follow your discipline.

Comment: ... or don't reload your .vimrc, just `:q` and restart.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake 3 autocommads isn't too bad, but maybe one of them is behaving poorly. You can at least clear `CursorMoved` autocmds via this command: `:au! CursorMoved` to see if that solves the issue. That allows you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Actually, `:au! CursorMoved` only removes non-grouped autocmds, it seems. So you will also have to remove each group specifically, eg `:au! matchparen`

Comment: Ok, so all I should do now, is scan my `vimrc` and group autocommands into `augroups` with `au!` on beginning, correct? Ill also delete those that I don't need.

Comment: Well, sure, that's a good practice. But to discover the root of your original issue, you should delete the `CursorMoved` groups one at a time to see which plugin (if any) was the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 101):

EDIT: Blogged about how this all works, with screenshots and awesome-sauce.

https://eduncan911.com/software/fix-slow-scrolling-in-vim-and-neovim.html

Original answer below...

---

```
:syntime on
```

move around in your ruby file and then

```
:syntime report
```

It reported the following slowest matching for me, and you can see that there are not even 1 match.

I disabled rubyPredefinedConstant in ruby.vim file and problem solved. Vim regex engine does not like something in ruby syntax highlight regex. You will have to find the balance between enough syntax highligting and a good performance.

Here is the top 3 slowest syntax highlighting regex for ruby reported on my Mac OS 10.8.5, homebrew Vim 7.4 (console vim)

```
  TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  3.498505   12494  0       0.008359    0.000280  rubyPredefinedConstant \%(\%(\.\@<!\.\)\@<!\|::\)\_s*\zs\%(STDERR\|STDIN\|STDOUT\|TOPLEVEL_BINDING\|TRUE\)\>\%(\s*(\)\@!
  2.948513   12494  0       0.006798    0.000236  rubyPredefinedConstant \%(\%(\.\@<!\.\)\@<!\|::\)\_s*\zs\%(MatchingData\|ARGF\|ARGV\|ENV\)\>\%(\s*(\)\@!
  2.438253   12494  0       0.005346    0.000195  rubyPredefinedConstant \%(\%(\.\@<!\.\)\@<!\|::\)\_s*\zs\%(DATA\|FALSE\|NIL\)\>\%(\s*(\)\@!
```

Or you can try `vim-ruby` as pointed out by Dojosto

Comment: +1. Lifesaving answer. Well, not _life_saving. But I had a 100 line `.rb` file that was loading like it was 100 million lines, and disabling `rubyPrefinedConstant` did the trick. Thank you @AskandLearn!

Comment: Can you explain how did you do it? Where should I put ruby.vim and what code should I use in that file to disable highlighting? Thank you !

Comment: @user1738342 Hi I am using boxen/homebrew so the location of my ruby.vim file is `/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/syntax/ruby.vim` If you using system default Vim, most likely it will be here `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax`. Just make sure the version number is correct.

Comment: How do you go about disabling something like `rubyPrefinedConstant` in vim?

Comment: This did make a difference and the syntime commands will definitely come in handy with future performance issues. But the real solution for me was installing [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport).

Comment: @dojosto, Thanks for that info, that should be a proper solution.

Comment: That is a sweet tool, very nice!

Comment: Same issue with rubyPredefinedConstant.. vim-ruby solved it!

Answer (score 29):

From [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902317/vim-slow-with-ruby-syntax-highlighting), I get vim fast by adding the following line in .vimrc file:
`set re=1`
This will force vim to use a older version of regex engine and it is actually FASTER for ruby.

Comment: This really worked for me too! It was hard to debug this (I had no idea it was syntax highlighting, commented out parts of the vimrc to get to this point. This one line fixed it! I put back relative number. Learned a lot, thanks!

Comment: FWIW: I just found that a `set re=1` in my vimrc was the _cause_ of syntax highlighting slowness! So this may not be good advice on modern vims

Answer (score 15):

I found that "set foldmethod=syntax" makes 7.4 almost unusable slow e.g. for js&ruby files (ubuntu 13.10) whereas "set foldmethod=indent" works fine.

Comment: The [FastFold plugin](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) makes it so folds are only recalculated on save. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26812154/79125

Comment: I have a pretty large .vimrc and I was happy to find this solution worked for me instantly. Cheers for that

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I had a `stray set foldmethod=syntax` in the `.vimrc` file, a bunch of lines down from a  `set foldmethod=indent`.

Comment: This issue will trip up users who don't do anything crazy with exotic plugins, who just edit a large C file with syntax highlighting. It doesn't affect navigation, but insertions of text are incredibly slow. Now I know why: Vim is recalculating the darned fold level for all 11,000 lines of the file!

Answer (score 15):

I've noticed that vim can slow down to a halt if you're using anything that dynamically changes the background color. Try turning off `:set cursorline` or `:set cursorcolumn` (if you have them set).

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to thank everyone helping me out on this issue. Good news is, my Vim is snappy again.

I've started with fresh Vim re-install. I've than added plugin by plugin, until I found the root of all evil.

```
Bundle "gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque.git"
```

Its a plugin that was causing me all this pain. Since I had it for a while, it wasn't a suspect, thats why I discovered it so late.
What this plugin does, is whenever it finds a word for color (eg red, green), or hex value (eg. #FFFFFF), it sets background color of the text to match the color that its describing. Brilliant idea, but seems like poor implementation.

Removing this plugin removed the lags.

But I didn't stop here. I've done a major cleanup of my .vimrc as well. Removed some more plugins I hadn't used. Grouped my `autocmd`s and removed unnecessary ones.

My Vim is very snappy now. I'm happy again.

Comment: I'd never heard of that plugin, but I've been looking for something like it. I eventually found https://github.com/chrisbra/color_highlight , which is probably a better implementation (Christian Brabandt has committed patches to Vim itself, so I assume he knows how to write a well-behaved plugin)

Comment: I couldn't help myself, I just checked [the source](https://github.com/gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque/blob/master/after/syntax/css/vim-coloresque.vim) and, indeed, the plugin is adding an expensive `CursorMoved` autocmd, and it doesn't prevent duplicate registrations.

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes another CursorMoved au that bothers me is https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/blob/master/autoload/airline/extensions.vim What do you think about this one?

Comment: airline is very well designed. I haven't had any problems with it. Are you still having slowness?

Answer (score 5):

Syntax highlighting can be slow, but that should be limited to some (somewhat pathological) files, and particular syntax(es). The latest Vim 7.4 has a new command `:syntime` to troubleshoot syntax highlighting slowness.

Apart from that, often, a *binary search* where you disable half of your plugins, then only one half of that (when the problem is still there), or the other half (when the problem vanished) lets you get to the problematic script quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that

```
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme candyman
```

have nothing to do with that lag. The two first lines are useless (the number of usable colors is defined according to your `$TERM` and your colorscheme already does `set background=dark`) but not really harmful.

Common "Vim is slowing to a crawl" causes include poorly written `autocmd`s, too many `autocmd`s, reloading one's `~/.vimrc` too often, poorly written plugins…

Please post your setup so that we can help you find out why you experience that lag.

Comment: I have posted my setup, if you've missed it, its on the bottom of post.

Comment: Sorry. I'd say that you have too many autocmds. Try commenting them out to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

I have had this problem for a long time, and it was driving me crazy. I tried installing [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby). Not sure if that helped but at least now I have the most up-to-date version of ruby syntax highlighting (with any performance improvements since the last version of Vim was released).

But then I looked further, and discovered that vim-ruby has a mode that skips all the expensive highlighting. Try adding this line to your vimrc and see if it helps (it did for me, finally!):

`let ruby_no_expensive=1`

Answer (score 1):

For me that was `set relativenumber` feature which was slowing it down. Try to disable it with `set norelativenumber` and test.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone out there:

I had accidentally created an extremely large tag file for my project; so my syntax highlighter was searching the large file to highlight function names.

So check your tag file! (In my setup I was using easy-tags so mine was placed at `~/.vimtags`

Answer (score 0):

Very late, but I figured this may help someone in a similar boat as me.

The plugin `vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight` turned out to be lagging my entire editor. They do mention on their [Github](https://github.com/tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight#mitigating-lag-issues) that people have reported lag issues, and offer some solutions.

So if anyone happens to be using that plugin, try using some of the fixes listed; [this one](https://github.com/tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight/issues/6#issuecomment-274411930) works, but you need to be selective about which languages you want to keep:

```
let g:NERDTreeSyntaxDisableDefaultExtensions = 1
let g:NERDTreeDisableExactMatchHighlight = 1
let g:NERDTreeDisablePatternMatchHighlight = 1
let g:NERDTreeSyntaxEnabledExtensions = ['c', 'h', 'c++', 'php', 'rb', 'js', 'css']
```