# `set foldmethod=syntax` makes vim slower, and `set foldmethod=indent` is not good enough, what can I do?

Tags: vim, folding

Before `set foldmethod=syntax`, my vim works like rocket, but everything changed after that, my vim works like tortoise, I can't bear the vim responding time.
so, I decided `set foldmethod=indent`, but it's not strong and smart enough.

And I try to write some vimscript, but it worths too much, what should I do?

**NOTE: I just want to fold my c++ code.**

Comment: I don't think you can do anything. / Opinion based? / Indent your code properly and it should not be a problem.

Comment: @user202729 I just want to fold my c++ code in vim (not include java, python or other languages), is it simpler ?

Comment: How you like your folding be folded?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916887/7976758 for possible cause and answers.

Comment: @dlmeetei Sometimes, I fold a little long snippet code to make it clear.

Comment: @phd Thanks for your reply, I checked the answer, didn't get satisfied one. if I `set complete=.`, my tags will not work.

Comment: Tried FastFold?

Comment: @phd Appreciate your reply, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's causing this without the problematic source code files. A lot of developers use Vim to edit C++ files (with syntax-based folding), so it's not a general problem. Do you have overly long files, a lot of nesting, or many `#ifdef`s?

I'm a bit surprised that it's just the folding part of the syntax that slows you down. Usually, it's the whole syntax parsing (on complex files), and only `:syntax off` can remedy that.

You may want to fiddle with the syntax sync options (`:help :syn-sync`). Also read `:help :syntime`; this can help with troubleshooting. I'm afraid there's no quick and easy fix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used `:syntime` to detect what happened, but I couldn't recover it. I just remembered I opened many files and wrote code in Vim, my auto-complete got very slow.

Comment: I don't see the connection between auto-completion speed and syntax folding. The latter typically affects cursor movement and scrolling speed. Also, if you want further help on this, it would be a good idea to include the `:syntime` results in the question and link to the corresponding source code you've used this on.

Comment: According to [this `vim-javascript` issue](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/issues/140#issuecomment-70144001) (referencing the article [Keep folds closed while inserting text](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text)) claims that the issue is with vim syntax folding,  Whatever it is, I've seen this issue with other languages as well and the [FastFold](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) plugin did seem to help in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

A bit old thread, but just in case, try the [FastFold](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) plugin, I've been having issues with a large PHP file, and after switching to this plugin my Vim is really snappy. And even other issues with some plugins like Quickjump seem to be gone.

Tip found in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2ln1hr/my_vim_was_slow_because_of_foldmethodsyntax_and/)